# Intuition behind entropy and its differentiation

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, pressure, entropy

I was reading the following paper about a better intuition of entropy and how it is connected to heat energy without the use of microstates:
[image]
[image]

The problem is when he assumed that volume is constant and replaced the ideal gas constant with its dependent components why did the author assume that pressure is also constant and not a function of temperature since as you change the temperature you can't keep  an isobaric isovolumetric process?

Comment: Honestly, I think that this calculation is completely wrong. If $c_v$ is constant, then there's no need to rewrite it with $pV/nT$, and $pV$ isn't constant. On the other hand, if you're talking about $S$ and not $U$, the calculation is still incorrect, but I think there's a way to give it meaning. Are you sure this is $U$, internal energy?

Comment: @Miyase, he is talking at this point about internal energy differential and I thought there is something wrong too especially in rewritting the constant (the constant and the equation it is put into are actually derived from each other (boltzmann const. x temperature)) . he is basically trying to prove that entropy is the differential of what he integrated. I am in dead need for some explanation of this approach because i can't really grasp the meaning of entropy contributing to internal energy and ......

Comment: ............i just don't want to let it pass by. I want to really be in the discoverer's boots so if you could help me in finding some reliable source i would be thankful.

Comment: @Miyase, I added the missing part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a development of my comment below the original question. I think that the calculation is wrong, even though the final result is correct.

For a monoatomic ideal gaz:

$$dU=\frac{3}{2}\,nR\,dT$$

As for entropy:

$$dS=\frac{dU+P\,dV}{T}$$

Without any assumption that $V$ or $P$ is constant:

$$dS=\frac{dU+P\,dV}{T}=\frac{3}{2}\,nR\frac{dT}{T}+\frac{P}{T}\,dV$$

Using $PV=nRT$ and integrating from initial state $(P_0,V_0,T_0)$ to current state $(P,V,T)$, it yields:

$$\Delta S=\frac{3}{2}\,nR\ln\left(\frac{T}{T_0}\right)+nR\ln\left(\frac{V}{V_0}\right)$$

If you assume that $V=V_0$, you get the result that you mention at the end of your post:

$$\Delta S=\frac{3}{2}\,nR\ln\left(\frac{T}{T_0}\right)$$

Yielding the correct end-result doesn't make the intermediary result you mentioned valid. $P$ isn't constant, and doesn't need to be, for this proof.